# How to omit container in docker container info module

Tags: ansible

I'm using the [`docker_container_info` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_container_info_module.html).

I need to omit a certain container:

```yaml
- name: Get infos on container
  docker_container_info:
    name: {{ container_name }}
    omit: omit if {{ container_name }} is CONTAINER_X [something like this]
  register: result
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?  It's unclear to me.

Ansible use the name of the container to uniquely identify the container it need to act upon in an "idem-potent" way.
If you don't want to take action, then you need to have the docker_fact to know if it already exist and then add a "when" clause.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement) statement that you can add on any Ansible task.

```yaml
- name: Get infos on container
  docker_container_info:
    name: {{ container_name }}
  when: container_name != 'CONTAINER_X'
  register: result
```

This will result in a skipped task if `container_name` is `CONTAINER_X`.

Answer (score 0):

The `docker_container_info` module extracts information about the given docker container and if you add register with a task, it will register the output in a variable(in your case result is the variable).

Firstly, If you don't want to run this for a specific container name, you can use something like this,

```
- name: Get container information
  docker_container_info:
    name: {{ container_name }}
  register: result
  when: container_name != "CONTAINER_X"
```

Secondly, If you have a list of container names on which you want to iterate and skip a particular container, then you can use something like this

```
- name: get container information
  docker_container_info:
    name: {{ item }}
  when: item != "CONTAINER_X"
  with_list: "{{ container_names }}"
  register: result
```